# Setting system properties for jar in web application

Tags: tomcat7, system-properties

i want to set system properties for jar in my web application?
The default value for key is set in jar using system.properties(),i m trying to pass value for this key from web application.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase your question? I do not understand, where is the problem and what is your question.

Comment: Thnks for help.i want to set system properties for jar from outside.I set -Dkey = value in setenv.sh file in tomcat,where value is file which assigning to key from web application,jar not getting the specified file,so it is throwing filenotfoundException.

Comment: So you set "key" property in script and when you seek it with System.getProperty("key"), it is not set, right?

Comment: it is set but jar not having file which is specified from outside (Web Application)..so it is giving exception...

Comment: So what is the problem? Paste your code and specify your problem exactly.